My peanut butter frosting is too dense and won't whip. How do I fix this?
Recipe for context:

3 cups confectioner's sugar
1 cup peanut butter
1/4 cup butter
1/4 cup milk
2 tsp. vanilla extract

As instructed, I mixed the wet ingredients with a hand mixer until fluffy. I then gradually added the sugar. The result turned out all clumped, almost like a Reese's cup center.
I didn't think that was the intended texture, so I added in more milk. Then it got too thin, so I tried adding more sugar, but that didn't quite help. It looked like the milk was seeping out of the mixture in the little creases and it had an oily sheen. I tried more butter, and it sorta helped? But not by much. I knew my butter was cold, so I let it warm up a bit before trying to whip it again. The consistency was much smoother, but it just wouldn't hold much air. I threw it back into the fridge to cool off a sec. No matter what I tried, it refused to whip up and maintain its shape. At this point I gave up. The end result is thick, dense, sticky. There's some air in it, but I suspect that it'll be gone by tomorrow.
I have a few guesses as to what went wrong:
A) I needed more room temp butter from the start.
B) I should have used cream in place of milk.
C) My hand mixer just wasn't powerful enough.
D) I needed to whip it longer before adding in the sugar.
E) I over-worked it.
Am I close on any of those guesses? If not, where am I going wrong? I'd love to know the science behind this if possible.

I wonder if this is a recipe that assumes a certain type of peanut butter. i.e. I suspect that an "all-natural, just ground peanuts" PB which needs to be mixed before use would behave very differently from the stuff that's more like peanuts, corn syrup, palm or soy oil, etc. that "spreads very easily" and which does not separate if left on the shelf. Both are "peanut butter" but they don't act the same in many ways.  What sort of PB did you use?

Someone made a really good point in the comments that this could be a matter of pure, no-additives peanut butter (which has zero emulsifying power) versus normal grocery store plant butter (which has some). It’s  also possible that the recipe author measures confectioners sugar differently than you do, with the result that you added more than they did. Adding more milk was the wrong way to cope with that, because it throws off the oil/water ratio. You should have added at most a bit more milk, and more butter and peanut butter. (Cream would also have been a a better option than milk, but still not on its own.) Letting it warm up was also a bad move.
